# Pourquoi ne pas réfléchir sur le pourquoi des règles ?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Merci de donner toutes les raisons des votes négatifs qu'a reçu cette question: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8306/la-concordance-dans-une-relative-clause-avec-que-lechapper-belle ?

> Commentaire d'un francophone:
>
> Laure a expliqué. Tu poses beaucoup de questions cherchant une raison profonde à ce qui n'en a pas. Les règles cherchent à décrire l'usage, elles ne le déterminent généralement pas bien qu'elles l'influencent parfois, et les exceptions sont là parce que la description est imparfaite.

Les questions ci-dessous sont dans le même style, or elles ont amené beaucoup de réponses. Par conséquent, pourquoi ce dédain pour cette question ? Il se peut qu'il ait bien des raisons profondes, donc pourquoi ne pas essayer de persévérer jusqu'à ce qu'on les découvre éventuellement ? Merci.

[Why is there a "me" in "je vais me faire l’avocat du diable"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/why-is-there-a-me-in-je-vais-me-faire-lavocat-du-diable)
[Why is “la/le” used more often than “un/une” for noun definitions?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/why-is-la-le-used-more-often-than-un-une-for-noun-definitions)
[Comment expliquer l'usage de « an » vs « en »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/comment-expliquer-lusage-de-an-vs-en)
[Comment expliquer l'origine de ce « de » dans l'expression « comme si de rien n'était » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6256/comment-expliquer-lorigine-de-ce-de-dans-lexpression-comme-si-de-rien-n)

Comment: Fermeture de la question: La question renvoie à une question qui a été supprimée à présent.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Aurais-tu un lien vers la question supprimée ? (J'imagine qu'on peut encore la trouver si on est capable de dire qu'une autre question y renvoie). J'aimerais comparer avant de voter la suppression.

Comment: On peut éventuellement la retrouver en utilisant web.archive.org, mais je ne pense pas que ça en vaille la peine, cette question  a eu une réponse plus bas, et elle porte sur une contestation sur le traitement d'une autre question, et la page de cette question n'existe plus sur le site, donc de toute façon, on ne peut rien faire.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Les questions et messages "supprimés" par leurs auteurs sont encore visibles sur le site. Si tu cliques sur le lien contenu dans la question tu la verras.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Ce n'est pas parce que tu ne peux pas toi voir la question qu'elle a été supprimée, elle est encore visible. Voir le [Help Centrer/Privileges](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: @Laure Ils sont visibles pour moi, mais je crois qu'ils le sont pas pour tout le monde. Si c'est comme la modération, c'est à partir de 2000 points pour les sites en bêta.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat C'est justement pour ça que je suggérais à  PERCE-NEIGE de lire le Help Centre. Tu demandais un lien...

Answer (score 6):

**1.** J'ai déjà expliqué et je vais donc répéter la même chose. 
Tu poses plusieurs questions sous un même titre "concordance" (je suppose tu veux dire par "accord" ?)

> Je vois au moins deux questions différentes et sans rapport dans cette
>   question confuse. 1) Une question sur sur l'accord du participe passé.
>   2) Une question sur l'expression "l'échapper belle" où il n'y a pas
>   aucun participe passé.

Nous t'avons déjà répondu qu'il ne faut pas chercher la logique dans les **règles d'accord du participe passé** en français, c'est peut-être ce qu'il y a de plus arbitraire en grammaire française avec des règles fabriquées et imposées par l'institution et qu'on ne peut qu'apprendre par coeur car il n'y a rien à comprendre. Je t'invite à lire en entier [l'article](http://www.aide-doc.qc.ca/le.grammairien/ftp/pp1.pdf) dont j'extrais cette longue citation :

> L’une des plus grandes difficultés du français écrit, sinon la plus
>   grande, pour la majorité des francographes, c’est l’accord du « 
>   participe passé ». Un historien de la grammaire scolaire, André
>   Chervel (1977 : en particulier 110-111), soutient d’ailleurs, avec
>   autant de sérieux que d’humour, que c’est essentiellement pour
>   enseigner et justifier l’accord du participe passé (ci- dessous
>   désigné par pp) que les classes de grammaire française ont été
>   inventées. Depuis trois siècles, et particulièrement dans le cas de
>   cette classe de mots, la noble tâche d’apprendre aux élèves à écrire
>   correctement ce qu’ils ne prononcent pas inspire des grammairiens et
>   des pédagogues de tout acabit. Dans des formulations plus ou moins
>   heureuses, chacun propose cinq, dix ou quinze règles « générales » et
>   jusqu’à une trentaine de cas particuliers ou d’exceptions.

**2.**  La question sur **l'échapper belle** n'a rien à voir avec le reste de ta question. Et on t'a déjà répondu :

> 3) Dans "l'échapper belle" *l'* et *belle* sont figés et neutres et ne
>   renvoient à rien du tout, on peut "échapper à" quelque chose, mais on
>   ne peut pas "l'échapper belle" à quelque chose.

Que voulais-tu donc qu'on te dise de plus ?

Je pense que nous comprenons tous bien ton désir d'apprendre pour améliorer ton français, et tu dois te dire que quand nous ne répondons pas c'est qu'il n'y a pas de réponses, et c'est ce que @Unfrancophone et moi t'avons dit et je ne vois pas comment nous aurions pu le dire autrement.

Si tu veux être sûr d'obtenir des réponses à tes questions assure-toi avant tout de ne poser qu'**une seule question à la fois**. Toutes les questions sur lesquelles tu fais un lien dans ta question ici-même ne porte que sur une seule chose et sont exprimée clairement, c'est peut-être pour ça aussi que les réponses y sont claires et tranchées. Ta question [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8167/quelle-est-la-nuance-entre-depuis-quil-a-eu-30-ans-et-depuis-quil-a-tren) était claire, elle a eu une réponse.

Un autre conseil que je peux te donner c'est d'essayer de travailler sur le vocabulaire avant de travailler sur la grammaire. Parfois on ne comprend pas ce que tu dis parce que ta façon d'employer les mots est étrange. Si tu fais des questions brèves et portant sur le vocabulaire peut-être arrivera-t-on à corriger tes erreurs plus facilement. Quand tu as des doutes sur l'emploi des mots essaie de poser des questions sur le chat à ce sujet, on t'y fera des traductions plus facilement.

Comment: Confusion possible du demandeur entre "concordance des temps" (grammaire) et "accord" (comme l'accord de l'adjectif avec le nom)